# How can I know the frequency ranges for the "frequency bins" in JavaFX MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

For a current project of mine it would be very helpful to be able to know the frequency ranges of the "frequency bins" as they are called in the docs.

The only thing the Javadoc says on this topic that I could find is:

> The number of bands in the audio spectrum. The default value is 128; minimum is 2. The frequency range of the audio signal will be divided into the specified number of frequency bins. For example, a typical digital music signal has a frequency range of [0.0, 22050] Hz. If the number of spectral bands were in this case set to 10, the width of each frequency bin in the spectrum would be 2205 Hz with the lower bound of the lowest frequency bin equal to 0.0.

<sub>From [the MediaPlayer docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#audioSpectrumNumBandsProperty--)</sub>

Now this is all nice and good but from what I understand this means that I have to first know the range of the audio signal, correct? Or is this premise incorrect and JavaFX bases everything on "a typical digital music signal"?

Note: This question does not ask how to get the frequency range of an audio file; just clarification on the documentation's text.